# How to change a 2D logo to an Angle in Illustrator or Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo

How can I take the first logo and Slant it to an angle in Illustrator or Photoshop?

Please look at the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Illustrator**

- Menu Effect > 3D > Rotate

[image: rotate]

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop:

Rotate it.

[image]

Then stretch it horizontally (or squeeze vertically)

[image]

It hasn't got any thickness. For it you must redraw it. 3D extrusion can be used to other parts, but not to the pointers. (Illustrator's 3D extrude has bevels, but they do not help). A real 3D program is needed, if you want apparent thickness and do not want to redraw it in 2D

Distorting it can create pespective, but that exaggerates the flatness.

**ADD** It surely is a good exercise to recolor the blue star for thickness.

Make it at first totally light blue, then decide the apparent top point, make selections for the darker areas with the polygonal lasso tool and fill them.

[image]

Now it screams for a perspective. See, how N and E pointers look out too big. The perspective can be added with Edit > Transform > Distort. Drag the top corners down and closer each other.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Use Ctrl+Drag on Transform Points in Photoshop

You can hold down the **Ctrl** key on the transform point while transforming an object (Ctrl+T). Or while you are in transform mode, you can **right-click** and select many options such as **Perspective** to get your desired effect.

Doing it this way will give you total **live** control.

---

Find out more here: Adobe: Video tutorial: [Free Transform command](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/photoshop/using/transforming-objects.html)

[image]

[image]